Authentication in MySQL from other docker containers
I have one docker container running docker with MySQL image. Say it's called sql.
This container has 2 databases: database1 and database2
I have created specific users for each database, say user1 full access to database1 and user2 full access to database2
Then I have two other docker containers with PHP image. Say one is called php1 and php2.
All 3 containers, sql, php1 and php2 are running in the same Docker network
The thing is that if I grant privileges to user1 and user2 say:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database1`.* TO 'user1'@'php1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database2`.* TO 'user2'@'php2';

Then if I try to login from php1 with:
mysql -p -u user1 -h sql

It cannot authenticate because it resolves the hostname with the network IP (for example 172.18.0.3) instead of using the hostname php1
The thing here is that I've read that there is a configuration in MySQL for my.cnf that I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this called skip-name-resolve
But according to this article: https://nixcp.com/skip-name-resolve/
Even if this could solve this issue, it hinders seriously the performance.
I wonder if anyone has any solution for this scenario.
One option could be fixing static IP to each docker instance and then, instead of using names for authentication, using the IP straight.
But I'm wondering if there is a better solution, other than using static IP or removing the skip-name-resolve directive that I'm completely ignoring.

After hitting my head for hours, the solution was the simplest I've could ever think
Instead of using the hostname in the GRANT query, I simply used the '%' wildcard to target all hosts for the same user.
I got the idea just by looking how the WordPress/MySQL docker composer file was made after running and checking their User table. They essentially do this to sort out the issue. Probably everyone does this, but if you plan to configure out everything by yourself, maybe you don't realize this at first.
